# Access debug variables from within the code

Tags: eclipse, debugging, odoo

It's about debugging in eclipse, 
While debugging, I can see `Variables` window containing the variable names and their values, how can I access those variables and get their values from within the code or (expression) window?

For example can I write  something like this:

```
print cash.dbname
```

or

```
x=cr.IN_MAX
```

or

```
s = _pool._serialized
```

(See the picture)

There's a very complex tree of variables, can I also access this variable tree reaching the branches and leaves?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried your suggestion? (Answer: yes, that should work)

Comment: great, thanks Joachim, so is there a way to search the variable tree to get a certain variable or value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the Display view; there you can enter code snippets that execute within the current stack frame selected in the Debug view. Code completion works, too.

[image]

You can select part or all of the contents of the Display view, right-click, and choose to Display, Inspect, or Execute it. Very powerful for exploring application state when debugging.

See also the [Eclipse Help page about Display View](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/display/ref-display_view.htm).